# Metric which doesn't separate points

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

My question is rather simple. Does the notion of a metric which doesn't separate points (i.e. a function which verifies all axioms of a metric except it doesn't separate points) make sense? Is it worth it to study one? Are there any important examples of such metrics?

Comment: What do you mean by *it doesn't separate points*? That $d(x, y) = 0$ iff $x = y$ does not hold?

Comment: Look up "pseudometric".

Comment: With the 'point seperation' do you mean the Hausdorf property?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, this is the idea behind a [pseudometric space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudometric_space).

---

This answers your question, but let me say a bit about the basic relationship between pseudometric spaces and metric spaces:

Any pseudometric space $(P, d_P)$ has a corresponding metric space $(M, d_M)$:

- Define an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $P$ by $a\sim b$ if $d_P(a, b)=0$.
- Note that by the triangle inequality, if $a\sim b$ and $c\sim d$ then $d_P(a, c)=d_P(b, d)$.
- So let $M$ be the set of $\sim$-equivalence classes of points in $P$ - in symbols, $M=P/\sim$ - and define the function $d_M([a]_\sim, [b]_\sim)=d_P(a, b)$. By the previous bullet point, $d_M$ is in fact well defined, and now it's not hard to show that $(M, d_M)$ is a metric space.

This construction in turn yields a weaker notion of similarity of pseudometric spaces than isometry: say two pseudometrics are *weakly isometric* if their *corresponding metric spaces* are isometric. E.g. the one-point pseudometric space, and the two-point pseudometric space where the two points are distance zero from each other, are weakly isometric but not isometric.

Comment: This is a fine answer, but I'd like to add a small follow-up. The original question also asked if there are any important examples of such metrics. To this the answer is YES. For example, the $L_p$ spaces of functions $f$ (say, complex-valued, on the interval $[0,1]$) with the metric $d_p(f,g) = (\int |f-g|^p)^{1/p}$; then $d_p(f,g) = 0$ if and only if $f=g$ a.e. (almost everywhere).

Comment: @ZachTeitler Quite right. Another important example, dear to my heart, is that of Gromov-Hausdorff. If we define the Gromov-Hausdorff distance on all isometry types of bounded metric spaces, this is clearly a pseudometric; however, it is not a metric (consider e.g. the unit disc versus the unit disc minus one point). Now on the (isometry types of) *compact* metric spaces, it is a metric - however, this is surprisingly hard to prove, and the only thing that's obvious is that it's a pseudometric!